# Could Yoda's backwards speech pattern be caused by the natural evolution of Galactic Standard?

Tags: star-wars, languages, yoda

Yoda is 900 years of age; given how much English and other languages have evolved over time, to a point were someone of this day and age would not be able to comprehend what an English speaker was saying only 300 years ago? Could Yoda be speaking correct Galactic Standard, only an older version that was no longer used?

Comment: Older versions of the Galactic Standard, there are not

Comment: You're statement about English does not apply. If you pick up a 1611 King James bible, you can still read it or understand it spoken to you. Stretching it a bit further, an Englishman _can_ understand a surprising amount of German.

Comment: yes but pronunciation was different ,and we dont actuly hear the language they speek in ,only its translation to english

Comment: Addressed directly in this answer to a different question: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/158150/69721

Comment: @kingleon mmm,very intresting tanks!

Answer (score 6):

### Canon: Most Likely Not

Star Wars Rebels' [Bendu](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Bendu) talks to Kanan and Ezra in modern Basic - unless you assume some form of Force communication translation (which I wouldn't since it's not telepathic or anything). According to the [official website](https://www.starwars.com/databank/bendu), it's an "ancient" being and can thus safely be assumed to be at the very least as old as Yoda, probably much older, I think.

It's still possible that Bendu updated his language skills while Yoda did not, but... that's probably really stretching it.

[Video link to Youtube: Kanan and Ezra talking to the Bendu](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oVyuB2ri61A)

### Legends: Definitely Not

According to [Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Galactic_Basic_Standard), referencing "The Written Word" and "Power of the Jedi Sourcebook" on it, modern Galactic Basic Standard was established after the Vultans joined the Republic around 14.000 BBY. The history of Galactic Standard is divided into eras - similar to real world languages - with "modern" Galactic Standard being the latest after Old and Mid-Galactic Standard. A major shift in the language, like turning grammar upside down from Yoda's to "regular" is, would certainly be considered a new distinct era.

Comment: English has also been establish since human got to England but It has also evolve

Comment: @joaosturza In the linked article there is a distinction between "Old Galactic Standard", "Mid-Galactic Standard" and modern "Galactic Standard Basic", just like English eras like Old, Middle, Early Modern, Modern English. That's why I specifically mentioned the "modern" variant, the latest stage of the language's evolution. Plus, in The Old Republic era, millenia BBY, modern Galactic Standard is spoken the same as we know it from the time around 0 BBY.

Comment: yes but we only hear it in english ,we dont know what the actual language sounds like ,the lenguage of the main protagonist is the comon language and we never saw yoda in his youth ,a argument can be made

Comment: @joaosturza Fair enough. Point about it all being translated to English taken. Still, the different eras of Galactic Standard are very indicative, imo. A major change like turning your sentences upside down, would call for a new, named era.