# How is Yoda's speech translated to non-English languages?

Tags: star-wars, languages, yoda

Yoda [infamously](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/158131/what-language-were-yodas-speech-patterns-based-on) speaks using the OSV (object, subject, verb) word ordering

> Much to learn, you still have.

rather the SVO ordering used in English

> You still have much to learn.

How is this dealt with in translations to other languages, particularly languages which don't use SVO word order, for example Japanese or Albanian? Do they just switch the words to OSV order? Does that even make sense in most other languages?

Comment: very carefully.

Comment: Very well, thank you!

Comment: You mixed up "infamously" and "incorrectly", as in, "it's incorrect that Yoda speaks OSV". It's more complicated than that (verb phrases in bold): "Your weapons; you **will not need** them." "No, there **is** another." "A Jedi **craves not** these things." "Luminous beings **are** we, not this crude matter." "**Will** he finish what he begins?" "He **is** too old." Etc., etc., etc. In ESB, he uses OSV in at most half of his sentences. This is why so many imitations of Yoda ring false.

Comment: @ToddWilcox But I think Chris meant to say famously too. Maybe "Yoda famously speaks using the incorrect OSV word ordering"

Comment: @ToddWilcox And re:your second point, I still think he speaks in OSV order more than the average person. And imitations/parodies are usually exaggerations of a certain quality.

Comment: @KodosJohnson You mean like the prequels?

Comment: Suggested title edit: "How Yoda's speech translated to non-English languages it is?"

Comment: And even two different orders in the same line: "Away put your weapons. I mean you no harm."

Comment: How is Yoda's speech translated to non-English languages? *Carefully very.*

Answer (score 61, accepted):

There's an interesting extract from The Open University's [OpenLearn](http://www.open.edu/openlearn/languages/english-language/may-the-forza-be-you-star-wars-other-languages#) website on precisely this:

> This is easily replicated in other languages that also have follow the SVO order, but others have to be more creative. In the German translation, instead of positioning the finite verb in second place in the sentences, it moves to the end, as in Eure Sinne nutzen ihr müsst (Your senses to use you have).

For reference, German is typically considered to use [V2 constituent order](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/1057/german-is-sov-should-it-not-have-been-ich-ein-berliner-bin)<sup>1</sup> word ordering, so ordinarily, the finite verb should be second. Instead, as stated in the source, the finite verb moves to the end of the sentence, which would likely sound unnatural to a native German speaker.

According to [The Atlantic](https://www.theatlantic.com/entertainment/archive/2015/12/hmmmmm/420798/):

> In Czech translations, rather than speaking in his general object-subject-verb manner, Yoda apparently speaks in subject-object-verb (like in Japanese).

Clearly, translators have simply adapted Yoda's word order to sound 'most foreign' (Czech is [pretty flexible with word order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Czech_word_order)).

I found a rather complete [list of languages and Yoda's word orders](https://www.reddit.com/r/linguistics/comments/gfoov/what_is_yodas_syntax_in_foreign_dubssubtitles_in/) on Reddit:

> - Czech: Free word order. Yoda speaks consistently in SOV. Interestingly enough, putting an object before a verb does sound unusual to most speakers of Czech.
> - Estonian: Free word order language. Yoda retains the English OSV order. *Note: This is grammatical in Estonian, but does make it seem as though Yoda is constantly stressing the object phrase as the main point of his statements. This gives his speech an unusual quality.*
> - French: An SVO language. Yoda speaks in OSV.
> - German: A SVO or SOV language. Yoda brings the Object to the front (OSV), like in English.
> - Hungarian: A free word order language. There is nothing unusual about Yoda's speech.
> - Italian: An SVO language. Yoda speaks in OSV. *Note: OSV is also the syntax used in the Italian of the less-proficient speakers of Italian from the region of Sardinia.*
> - Japanese: An SOV language. Yoda seems to use a more or less correct syntax, with a more archaic vocabulary.
> - Korean: An SOV language. Nothing is unusual about Yoda's grammar.
> - Norwegian: An SVO language. Yoda speaks in OSV.
> - Romanian: An SVO language. Yoda speaks in OSV. He also places adjectives before the noun instead of after the noun, and uses an archaic form of the future tense.
> - Spanish: An SVO language. Yoda speaks in OSV.
> - Turkish: An SOV language. Yoda speaks in OSV. *Note: This order is also used in classical Ottoman poetry, so the syntax may have been chosen in order to emphasize Yoda's wisdom or age.*

Generally, OSV is a safe bet for translators, because [practically no natural language uses it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_order#Phrase_word_orders_and_branching)—Wikipedia rounds the value to 0%, and the [original source](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-linguistics/article/tomlinrussell-s-basic-word-order-functional-principles-london-croom-helm-1986-pp-308/7542AFB4A8B28D651F6E109B810F4C04) of that data quotes 0.00%. I can't imagine many of the languages (if any) that Star Wars has been translated into use OSV naturally; the only example Wikipedia lists of a common OSV language is [Warao](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warao_language), which only has around 28,000 speakers (and no Star Wars translation that I could find).

So, in short, **yes, translators try to pick a word order which is 'foreign' to the language, and don't rigidly stick to OSV**.

---

<sup>1</sup> I had originally stated SOV, but as noted in the comments, this wasn't a particularly accurate characterisation, and more misleading than helpful.

Comment: I'm sorry, but german ist not an SOV language, at least not in the normal form. And in fact except for a few things from "A new hope" I can't remember anything else then OSV from Yoda.

Comment: Since this is an exception I would like to comment on Hungarian. My native language is Hungarian, and as a former journalist I am pretty well versed in grammar and I can confirm Yoda speaks totally normally.  In an [interview](http://tinyurl.com/l4knx3o) Tibor Kosztola, the (co)director of all three dubs says the public would've thought they made a mistake while recording the dub  if they made Yoda's speech artificially broken (this was the 80s, he is not wrong, some dubs were interesting). Although he admits he didn't compare the dub to the original. I'll try to find the translator's opinion.

Comment: One more note: Yoda's dubbed voice in the '95 and '97 dub (but not in the '82 one) is a humorist who also dubbed Mr. Burns from Simpsons and Mr Jinks from Pixie and Dixie and Mr. Jinks and his voice sounds like an incredible mismatch to me when he talks about "For my ally is the Force, and a powerful ally it is. Life creates it, makes it grow. Its energy surrounds us and binds us" -- it's impossible to take anything seriously spoken by that voice.

Comment: So people in the real world use the same grammar than Yoda and that's normal. You made my day.

Comment: No, what I am saying is that the translation is made into normal speech patterns.

Comment: I can add Yoda speaks in SOV (or even OVS sometimes) in the Russian translation, pretty much like the Czech one. There is free word order in Russian, but object before a verb sounds unusual as well.

Comment: The German is more like “Use your senses you have to”. And the V in SOV is not in second position, so your characterisation of German is just wrong. Your source only states that German has the finite verb last in *dependent clauses*.

Comment: The footnote you've added is completely ridiculous. First you make a claim about German word order that is patently false, then you add a footnote admitting that it's false, but saying that the point isn't important anyway, which leads me to wonder why you bothered writing the false statement to begin with. (Furthermore, the example you cite doesn't use OVS.) I'm disappointed that this answer has attracted so many upvotes. It not only repeats errors in its sources, but also compounds them.

Comment: @Psychonaut You're right, I've just reread my answer and to be honest, the initial part about German being SOV was just plain wrong. I've edited to hopefully be more faithful to the truth; let me know if that's more accurate, or if I've missed something else.

Comment: Yes, it's much better now.  Thanks!